# Как подключить домен к двум сайтам?

Tags: домен

Можно ли подключить один домен например (site.ru) к двум сайтам которые одинаковы, но располагаются на разных хостингах. И как сделать что бы можно было самому переключать к какому хостингу сегодня будет подключаться домен?

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать что бы один домен был привязан к двум хостингам, прописав в настройках домена dns записи от двух хостингов. Выбирать к какому хостингу будет подключен домен сегодня, завтра и так далее нельзя.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ